# Using class based views to process information?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I've been experimenting with Django's Class Based Views and am trying to write a simple class based view that processes certain information in `request` so that the processed information can be used by the "handler" method.

I don't seem to have fully understood what the docs say and am unsure of whether this should be a Mixin, a generic view or something else. I'm thinking of making a class like this:

```
class MyNewGenericView(View):

    redirect_on_error = 'home'
    error_message = 'There was an error doing XYZ'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.process_information(request)
            # self.process_information2(request)
            # self.process_information3(request)
            # etc...
        except ValueError:
            messages.error(request, self.error_message)
            return redirect(self.redirect_on_error)
        return super(MyNewGenericView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def process_information(self, request):
        # Use get/post information and process it using
        # different models, APIs, etc.
        self.useful_information1 = 'abc'
        self.useful_information2 = 'xyz'

    def get_extra_info(self):
        # Get some extra information on something
        return {'foo':'bar'}
```

This will allow someone to write a view like:

```
class MyViewDoesRealWork(MyNewGenericView):
    def get(self, request, some_info):
        return render(request, 'some_template.html',
            {'info':self.useful_information1})

    def post(self, request, some_info):
        # Store some information, maybe using get_extra_info
        return render(request, 'some_template.html',
            {'info':self.useful_information1})
```

Is the above code the right way to go? Is there any simpler/better way of doing this? Will this prevent the above functionalities from being used in another generic view (e.g. a built-in generic view)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I just asked a stupid question.

This can easily be achieved by making a class that processes that information:

```
class ProcessFooInformation(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
    @property
    def bar(self):
        baz = self.request.GET.get('baz', '')
        # do something cool to baz and store it in foobar
        return foobar
    # etc...
```

Then using old style function views or new class-based views:

```
def my_view(request):
    foo = ProcessFooInformation(request)
    # use foo in whatever way and return a response
    return render(request, 'foobar.html', {'foo':foo})
```

I also made this more efficient by using lazy evaluation of properties.

I adapted ideas from the [lazy property evaluation recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/363602-lazy-property-evaluation/) and the comments to write a wrapper:

```
def lazy_prop(func):
    def wrap(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not func.__name__ in self.__dict__:
            self.__dict__[func.__name__] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.__dict__[func.__name__]
    return property(wrap)
```

This evaluates the value of the wrapped method only once per instance and uses a stored value on subsequent calls. This is useful if the property evaluates slowly.

Comment: Please post an answer if you think there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. great example code. http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/get-and-post-handling-in-django-views

Comment: I don't think that answers my question. I'm trying to use class based views so that actual views can extend a generic view and have the incoming information processed for them. The post that you have linked to simply separates GET and POST requests into two different methods, which isn't what I'm trying to do.